# find different matches and resort array in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sorting

I'm wondering how one would resort an array based on whether or not a property exists within each object. this is what would come back from the backend, only one has the something field, and only one has a false value for its isActive property.

I'd need the one or ones that has a something property sorted to the top of the array and secondly all the ones with a true value for its isActive property comes before the ones with false.

so this

```html
    var obj = [
      {
        "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164802",
        "isActive": false
      },
   {
        "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803",
        "isActive": true
      },
      {
        "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804",
        "isActive": true
      },       
      { 
       "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164801",
        "isActive": true,
        { "something": "xyz" }
      },
    {
        "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164806",
        "isActive": true
      },
        {
        "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164807",
        "isActive": true
      },
        {
        "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164808",
        "isActive": true
      },
        {
        "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164809",
        "isActive": true
      },
        {
        "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164810",
        "isActive": true
      }
    ]
```

would become

```html
        var obj = [
          { 
           "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164801",
            "isActive": true,
            { "something": "xyz" }
          },
       {
            "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803",
            "isActive": true
          },
          {
            "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804",
            "isActive": true
          },       
 
        {
            "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164806",
            "isActive": true
          },
            {
            "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164807",
            "isActive": true
          },
            {
            "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164808",
            "isActive": true
          },
            {
            "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164809",
            "isActive": true
          },
            {
            "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164810",
            "isActive": true
          },
          
          {
            "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164802",
            "isActive": false
          },
        ]
```

two different types of searching and matching and then an array.push? would helpers like lodash be practical, would it be easier with jQuery or can it simply be done with vanilla js?

Comment: the brackets around the "something" prop make it invalid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
var arr = [{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164802","isActive":false,"something":"xyz"},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803","isActive":false},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164801","isActive":true,"something":"xyz"},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164806","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164807","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164808","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164809","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164810","isActive":true}];


arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  if(a.hasOwnProperty("something") && !b.hasOwnProperty("something"))       // if a has the property "something" and b doesn't
    return -1;                                                              // then put a above b
  else if(!a.hasOwnProperty("something") && b.hasOwnProperty("something"))  // otherwise if b has the property and a doesn't
    return 1;                                                               // then put b above a

    // otherwise, either both or none of them have it (then sort using the property "isActive")
    return a.isActive? -1: 1;   // if a has "isActive" set to true put it on top of b without checking for b's "isActive", otherwise, put it below
});

console.log(arr);
```

**Edit:**

```js
var arr = [{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164802","isActive":false,"something":"xyz"},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803","isActive":false},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164801","isActive":true,"something":"xyz"},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164806","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164807","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164808","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164809","isActive":true},{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164810","isActive":true}];


arr.sort(function(a, b) {
  var aHasIt = a.something && a.something.length > 0,
      bHasIt = b.something && b.something.length > 0;
  if(aHasIt && !bHasIt)
    return -1; 
  else if(!aHasIt && bHasIt)
    return 1;

    return a.isActive? -1: 1;
});

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: thanks for a great explantion of it.

one more thing

var arr = [{"_id":"58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164801","isActive":true,"Something": [{ "xyz": "xyz" }]}];

how do I use hasOwnProperty to simply check if Something has any objects inside of it or not?

Comment: @totalnoob You mean to check if `something` has something in it?

Comment: yea, within your plugin. if instead of checking whether or not "something" exists, it'll check if there are any objects inside of "something" instead. would it be more like  if((a.something.length > 0) ?

Comment: @totalnoob If `something` doesn't contain anything then just sort it using its `isActive` no matter where it is in the resultant array. Right?

Comment: Check the **EDIT:** section above!

Comment: @totalnoob Just note that in the later edit, if an object has it `something` empty then it's position will only rely on its `isActive` property. That mean othe objects that doesn't have `something` at all could be above it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how I would do it in ES6.

The sort logic below simply tests the existence of the property `something`, if it doesn't, then checks the property `isActive`

```js
let obj = [
  {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803",
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803",
    "isActive": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804",
    "isActive": true
  },
  {
   "_id": "58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164801",
    "isActive": true,
    "something": "xyz"
  }
  ];

obj.sort((a, b) => (
  (a.hasOwnProperty('something') || b.hasOwnProperty('something'))
    ? 1                     // if the above line evaluates to  true, return one
    : (a.isActive ? -1 : 1) // else evaluate this 
));
console.log(obj);

// [ { _id: '58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164801',
//     isActive: true,
//     something: 'xyz' },
//   { _id: '58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804', isActive: true },
//   { _id: '58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164804', isActive: true },
//   { _id: '58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803', isActive: false },
//   { _id: '58f8ffe7ce2bbf01c6164803', isActive: false } ]
```

Comment: could you provide some details as to what it does since it's so simplified?

Comment: I updated my answer. There isn't much es6 going on except for the arrow function. I basically use [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) for brevity. The ternary operator can also be nested, which is what I did. First check if `something` property exists, then check is `isActive` evaluates to true.